# how to merge a CssStyleCollection with a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style

Tags: asp.net, css, listitem

i have a listitem and i want to set its style using a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style but there is not mergestyle like there is on controls. there is a Attributes.CssStyle which is of type CssStyleCollection but it wont merge with the Style class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListItem l = list.Items.FindByValue((String)e.Value);
if (null != l)
{
    CssStyleCollection csc = AnswerItemStyle.GetStyleAttributes(list);
    foreach (String key in csc.Keys)
    {
        l.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(key, csc[key]);
    }
}
```

For those who need it in future. Thanks for answer SO, dont know why i bothered asking.